# What time format is used by this webpage?

Tags: r, time

I am trying to scrape some data from an internet API. It has some time data that is represented as "1647257309550" and should refer to 2022.

What time format is that? How can I transform the data using R?

I tried

```
as.POSIXct(1647257309550, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

but that failed.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(1647257309550/1000, origin = '1970-01-01')`

Comment: `1647257309550` is milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct(1647257309550/1000, origin = '1970-01-01',tz = 'GMT')
[1] "2022-03-14 11:28:29 GMT"
```

Note that you do not need the `tz` argument

```
as.POSIXct(1647257309550/1000, origin = '1970-01-01')
[1] "2022-03-14 04:28:29 PDT"
```